# Best way to add new columns

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

What are best practices around adding new columns to tables? How do people usually do this since non-NULL defaults aren't allowed?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps:

1. Create your new column.
2. Run a job that populates the new
   column however you wish. If you don't have too much data, you could
   have a single process that updates every row (or perhaps does it in
   batches of N for slightly better performance).  Or you could use
   Dataflow for bulk import. Or you could have your application code do
   it, but it must be tolerant of NULL values.
3. [optional] If you
   want to add a `NOT NULL` constraint, you can do it (assuming you've
   actually populated every row). If you have other processes that are
   adding rows in parallel, then those processes will need to be
   updated to also populate your new column, else you'll be playing a
   never-ending game of catch-up. Note that, when a `NOT NULL`
   constraint is added, cloud spanner initiates a background process to
   validate your data (i.e. checks that all cells are not null) before
   actually finalizing the schema change. More info on data validation
   is [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-and-data-model#schema_changes_that_require_data_validation).
4. At this point, you can update your application code to
   start reading & depending on your new column.

More info is [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-and-data-model#supported_schema_updates).